# Having trouble with windows 10 task scheduler

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks, cpu-usage

I have recently upgraded my windows 8.1 to 10, And now each time I leave my laptop on its own after a few minutes the CPU and Disk usage both go really up due to scheduled tasks.

I tried disabling unnecessary tasks which I found, but nothing has been changed at all.

How can I adjust some basic settings like disabling these tasks on battery power or make the system wait more on idle state?

Comment: this is the idle maintenance tasks that run if the device is idle

Answer (score 0):

So I suppose that your CPU and disk usage are not related to these scheduled tasks.
Maybe you have a background running software (like an antivirus) which was installed while you were using Windows 8 and which is not compatible anymore with your Windows 10 ?

Try to disable temporarily everything launched at startup using [MSConfig](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-10/how-to-open-msconfig-in-windows-10) and disabling the boxes selectively : http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wiki/windows_10-update/msconfig-the-system-configuration-tool/273dea8e-4cbe-47e9-8489-f400e879ce17

As soon as you will have identified the faulty software, try to upgrade it or uninstall it completely if you don't need it.

Comment: The only protector of my system is basically windows defender, and when I open task manager to detect what is keeping the CPU high, I see "host process for windows tasks", is it possible that something else than scheduled tasks are causing this in your opinion?

Comment: P.S by using Process Explorer I can see that something named as "energytask.dll" has 25% CPU usage, do you know what it might be related to?